# How to autosize the UITableViewCell to fill all devices by Autolayout xib?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, xib

[image]

In the picture, it shows that Autolayout can only give a settled size(like 132*59 in the pic) to UITableViewCell. If I want to have a cell which has a size of 375*667 on iphone 6s and has a size of 414*736 on iphone 6s plus. That means the cell's size is the whole screen. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell will get width of UITableView, so you can attach UITableView's anchors to its superview:

```
[tableView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: tableViewSuperview.leftAnchor].active = YES;
[tableView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: tableViewSuperview.rightAnchor].active = YES;
```

Or just attach it via storyboard.

Height of cell you can return from delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Or also set it in storyboard (it's not quite suit your needs, as you want to set height equal to your view height)

If UITableView superview doesn't have size of device, you can get screen size from

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.bounds.size
```

Comment: So, there is no pure Autolayout way to solve this problem ?  We have to use code here ?

Comment: You can use autosize for height of your cell, but I don't think it's a better way. What do you mean by pure autolayout? You have to determine height of content somehow, to use its intrinsic size.